# Is this right that the fate of space expansion depends on matter density inside the universe?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, density, cosmological-constant

Is it right think that a right amount of matter density inside the universe could eventually stop the expansion of the universe or the expansion of space is something intrinsic only to space so the matter and space expansion are not interdependent?

Answer (score 1):

General relativity is the theory of how matter affects space (tells it how to bend) and space affects matter (tells it how to move). The equations governing the expansion of the Universe are derived from General Relativity. The expansion of space thus depends on the matter and energy density, and indeed, enough hypothetical matter density in the Universe could have eventually stopped the expansion of the Universe. But that does not seem to be the Universe we live in: our Universe does not have enough matter density, and has enough dark energy, that space is accelerating its expansion.

Answer (score 0):

In your explanation you seem to saying one of two things using the phrase "space is accelerating its expansion". Those can be interpreted either as:

1. As something has moved further away from an observer, it will then be moving away faster.
2. As time passes, if a new object is at the same distance as a previous object, the new object will be moving away faster then the previous object.

#1 is a statement that the Hubble constant H_0 specifies that the velocity an object moves away is proportional to its distance. This is an OK interpretation.
#2 seems to be saying that as time passes the value of H_0 changes so that the velocity away at a given distance gets larger. This is theoretically possible depending on the values of the four Omega terms in the Friedmann equation. Based on the values presently found to be pretty definite within small ranges of variation, as time passes, at any specific distance (not too near a mass with a large gravitational field) the velocity that a new object moves away will be smaller than a previous object's velocity was at the same distance it moved away.